# Does anyone know how keydb works internally and how it works on multi threading or have any source for that?

Tags: internals, keydb

I recently had a chance to explore the keydb. And now i need lots of clarifications that how they work with multi threading. In keydb we give the thread count in config files and during the server start up keydb initialise and create a threads and each thread had a separate event loops.
If the client connect to the server, clients actually connected to the threads and the threads have to read and process the commands and i heard that it uses fastlock for concurrency problems and then the threads are send the response to the client. This is my understanding anyone have the answers???

I want to know internal work of keydb